# I am wondering how could output these values on sql

Tags: sql

Business,
Luxury,
Minivan or SUV,
Executive van,
Armored Sedan,
Armored Minivan,
Minibus

They are on the same table and the column name is Vehicletype.
My question is that if used ORDER BY ASC it won't come up to the arrangements above.

Answer (score 2):

`ASC` orders alphabetically ascending. If you need to change that order to something else, add another column (for instance, `SORTORDER`) of a numeric type and `ORDER BY` that column, even if you don't display it.

```
VehicleType         SortOrder
-----------         ---------
Business               1
Luxury                 2
Minivan or SUV         3
Executive van          4
Armored Sedan          5
Armored Minivan        6
Minibus                7

SELECT VehicleType FROM whatever ORDER BY sortorder ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It's typical to use a conditional statement for this to introduce a number for the position. As part of your `SELECT`, you can use:

```
 CASE WHEN Vehicletype='Business' THEN 1
      WHEN Vehicletype='...' THEN 2
      WHEN ...
      ELSE NULL
 END AS position
```

or simpler in this case:

```
 CASE VehicleType
 WHEN 'Business' THEN 1
 WHEN '...' THEN 2
 END AS position
```

Then, use `ORDER BY position`.

Comment: Thank you sir, im new to this CASE syntax using sql.

Comment: @JRicPeteros: You should probably show your query and how you are trying to apply this or any other solution (preferably *not* in a comment but in your original post, use the *Edit* link under your question). That way it will be clearer what you are missing or where you are mistaken.

Comment: @JRicPeteros, it would also help to know which RDBMS you're using (MySQL, MS SQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, ...?).

Answer (score 0):

ASC will output the column alphabetically. And DESC will output the opposite.